# redirecting /index.php to / results in infinite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file contains this and only this:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php /
```

When I visit http://www.mydomain.com/ in Chrome I get this:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When mod_index takes the request `/` and maps it to `/index.php`, the `Redirect` statement that you have redirects it back to `/`. This is causing the loop. You can match against the actual request using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What does the `\` do in the `RewriteCond` before the `/index\.php`?

Comment: Oh - you're escaping the space. So `GET /index.php` will match but `GET /whatever/index.php` won't. Is that correct?

Comment: @neubert yeah, you can add extra capture group there if you want it to handle all index.php's: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ (.*/)index\.php` then make the rule: `RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]`